# Bootstrap - custom hamburger menu icon from image sourced in CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hamburger-menu

I am hacking away at website project and am struggling to get the bootstrap dropdown icon to display from custom CSS when screen width is sufficiently small. Im sure it is something stupidly simple but cant seem to figure it out.

Ends up looking like a checkbox:

[image]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Website Name</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <a href="#" id="test-icon">
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img alt="logo" src="images/db_logo_clean_60.png"</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    #test-icon {

    display: hidden;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #515151 url(../images/menu-icon.png) center;


}
```

Comment: `display:hidden` isnt a thing, also if its a `a` element, you need to give it `display:block` or `display:inline-block` to give it height and width parameters. It does appear though that the `a` isnt even displaying inside the `navbar-toggle`. Perhaps, skip the middleman and just apply the `background` to the `navbar-toggle`?

Answer (score 1):

Just modify the standard bootstrap navbar according to your css-- Check the css the way I improvised--

**working example**

```css
 .navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle .test-icon  {
    background-color: #fff;
    background:  url(https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ui-icons-pack/100/ui-icon-pack-01-512.png) center;
}
.navbar-toggle .test-icon {
    display: block;
    width: 22px;
    height: 2px;
    border-radius: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      
      <style type="text/css">
     


       </style>
       <script type="text/javascript">
        
       </script>
       </head>
      
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        
         <a href="#" class="test-icon"></a>
        <!--<span class="test-icon"></span>
        <span class="test-icon"></span>--> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img alt="logo" src="images/db_logo_clean_60.png"</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
</div>

</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: I have choosen my own hamburger image from the internet..just replace it with yours.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Simple css Solution

```
.navbar-header button.navbar-toggle {
    display: none;
}
```

If you can access the HTML so remove the button

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"><a href="#" id="test-icon"></a></button>
```